# The sed command does nothing

Tags: scripting

I am trying to change the name of a file using the sed command and it is just not working.

I have tried:

```
a)root@ubuntu:/test# sed 's;/test/testfile/;/test/testfile1/;'

b)root@ubuntu:/test# sed "s;/test/testfile/;/test/testfile1/;"
```

and also tried

```
c)root@ubuntu:/test#sed 's/\test\/testfile\//\/test\/testfile1\//'

d)root@ubuntu:/test#sed "s/\test\/testfile\//\/test\/testfile1\//"
```

The cursor enters newline and just hangs there. I have to ctrl+c  out of it.Is the syntax wrong or am i running it incorrectly?. I am new to this and  just testing this command on my linux system.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `sed` is waiting for you to give it some input to work on. Also, `sed` is not for renaming files. You need to use `mv` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to rename file `test` to `testfile`, then you don't want `sed` at all. You just want

```
mv test testfile
```

The `sed` command is for manipulating a stream of lines of text, not for renaming files.